# A member function of an object, is returning NoneType, even when it is actually returning -1

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a class with a method called `__parse_asup_file_for_lrepl_client_time_stats(self,start,end)`

The method just searches in one log file between 2 strings, and returns the information read. However if the start and end strings are not found in the file, I do return a -1 (because the file does not contain the required information)

```
def __parse_asup_file_for_lrepl_client_time_stats(self,start,end):
   if(found_start and found_end):
        ...
        ...
   else: 
       _log.warning("There is no info, I am returning -1")
       return -1
```

I call the method this way:

```
r=dd.parse_asup_file_for_replication_contexts_info() 
print ("R value is:",r)
print("Type of R is",type(r))
```

My problem is that when executing the code, even when I do see the message "There is no info, I am returning -1", the value of R is `None` and the type is `NoneType`

```
WARNING  There is no info, I am returning -1
R value is: None
Type of R is <class 'NoneType'>
```

For me clearly this is not a function without any return. The message "There is no info, I am returning -1" is displayed, so the return is returning -1

Why r is NoneType?

Comment: What does `dd.parse_asup_file_for_replication_contexts_info` do? It is better if you post a [mcve].

Comment: `__parse_asup_file_for_lrepl_client_time_stats` is not called anywhere in your examples. You probably don't return anything from `if(found_start and found_end)` block.

Comment: Post a complete example that shows the problem, not pseudo-code. For example your “call” to `dd.parse...` isn’t calling the method you show the `def __parse...`, and no parameters are provided in the call to `dd.parse...` where `__parse...` requires parameters. Fail, it will.

Comment: I call the method here: r=dd.parse_asup_file_for_replication_contexts_info()
I know that I reach the else part because the message "There is no info, I am returning -1" is displayed. However, when the function returns, the value of r is none and the type is NoneType

Comment: Again, what does `parse_asup_file_for_replication_contexts_info` do? Is `__parse_asup_file_for_lrepl_client_time_stats` called by a third intermideate function? What does `parse_asup_file_for_replication_contexts_info` return? Your `__...` function only returns the -1 value to the object that called it. If that object doesn't have a `return` statement, it will return `None`. We can't help you if you don't provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score -2):

I know now what the issue was.

I was just calling the member function, from inside another member function. So the scope of r was local to the calling member function and not existent outside it.

Newbie mistake, sorry.